# Revert Code to Previous Commit in Master

Tags: git

I have checked in code into my local master git repo and then pushed it up to origin.  There is only 1 such erroneous checkin.  What is the best way to revert the last commit locally and remotely?

I'd prefer to destroy the history.

Comment: It depends whether you want to destroy history.

Comment: Yes I prefer to destroy the history

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to undo the last commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-commit)

Comment: I would think someone with 10k reputation would know better; search on google/stackoverflow first before asking the same question all over again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are **sure** nobody has done a fetch/pull from the repo since you made the commit, do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push -f
```

If someone has already fetched/pulled, however, there is not much you can do without their cooperation. In that case, your best bet is doing a `git revert HEAD`, which will make an additional commit that undoes your last commit.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite history to remove that commit by using `git rebase -i <any earlier commit>`.
If it's the most recent commit, you can also just run `git reset --hard HEAD^`.

You can then run `git push -f` to rewrite the remote history.  This will break anyone who pulled that commit.

Comment: Are you sure that HEAD^ will give remove the last commit?

Comment: Is it not git push origin master -f?

Comment: @SachinKainth: `git reset` will reset the local branch to point to the that commit.  `HEAD^` means `HEAD`'s immediate parent.